# Getting output from the subprocess.Popen command into a webpage? (maybe an apache issue)

Tags: apache, cgi-bin, subprocess

Here is my program
    import subprocess

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "File starting to execute"
print "<br>"
proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "python", "test3.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = proc.stdout.read()
print "output is %s" %output

print "<br>"
print "File Executed Awesomely"
```

So when I run it from the command line it works great, like follows->

```
[root@localhost html]# python test2.py
Content-type:text/html


File starting to execute
<br>

output is .
Sent 1 packets.

<br>
File Executed Awesomely
[root@localhost html]#
```

that is perfect the ". Sent 1 packets." is what I want.  But when I run it from the webpage, the webpage just has

```
File starting to execute
output is
File Executed Awesomely
```

so I originally thought this was because I was doing something wrong grabbing the output but I listened on the port with wireshark (my other program it calls send a packet) and it looks like no packets shows up via the webpage call, but it does when I call it on the command line (the same way).  Looking at my apache error_log->

```
[Wed Jan 18 18:15:11 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Jan 18 18:15:11 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Jan 18 18:15:11 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Jan 18 18:15:11 2012] [warn] ./mod_dnssd.c: No services found to register
[Wed Jan 18 18:15:11 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

any suggestions on how I can fix it so my apache cgi-bin script runs the same way as the command line?

EDIT: looking at the log after a few calls it does this repeatedly

```
[Wed Jan 18 18:22:37 2012] [error] [client 10.117.153.89] :
[Wed Jan 18 18:22:37 2012] [error] [client 10.117.153.89] sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` is the key. First of all, letting your apache run sudo is dangerous to say the least, but if you really really want to do it... there's a way, edit `/etc/sudoers` (`visudo`) and locate the `Defaults    requiretty` part (`man sudoers`).

NB: Never let apache run anything using sudo, specify exactly what it needs to do and nothing more!

BTW: It may still not work if you have SELinux enabled or other LSM module.

Comment: this is exactly what I need, I will click the check mark! (it won't let yet, something about a 3 minute time limit, you are fast!) sorry i am using SCAPY in the other program which requires root access to run, and this is the best work-around I can find, thanks a lot.

Comment: BTW2: take a look at the communicate method in the subprocess module.

Comment: If the command you are running takes a lot of time maybe you can write a socket service apache can communicate with. When you need the data you send the request and the service returns you a session id and no data yet. Then from the web page (javascript or redirect) poll it asking for the output from that session till it is ready. This way your web script won't need 3 minutes uninterrupted execution. Yeh, way more complicated but... the other solution is rising this limit in apache.

Comment: mmm do you have a link or example of that, that sounds neato

Comment: Unfortunately we use that architecture in a project I can not share. When you see a progress bar (say on www.skyscanner.net) most of the time that's basically what they do - ask a question and then poll for the answer. I's better to build the service in such way that apache has only predefined set of commands that can be executed, good to have if hacked somehow.